# SSRS report Showing or hiding a rectange with a parameter leaves a blank area

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

I am using SQL Server 2012 Visual Studio 2010

I've toggled the visibility of a rectangle that's contained in a subreport based on the value of a parameter called Show Performance. This is working, however the body of the report behind the rectangle still appears if Show Performance is set to 'False'. I want to hide both the rectangle and the body of the report behind the rectangle. What's the best way to do this?

Visibility of Rectangle based on expression used in parameter
[image: 1]

**True**
[image: 1]

**False**
Note the blank space where the rectangle is. Ideally I want this space to disappear and the report size to shrink.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. I created a table then I created a second subreport. I placed the second subreport which contained the report without the lower table that was creating the whitespace in the second row of the table. I then set the row visibility on the two subreports to adhere to the report parameter.

[image: Solution]